# Flask mqtt works fine in the web app console (pythonanywhere) but it doesn't work in the web app itself,

Tags: flask, mqtt, pythonanywhere

I use [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) for my IoT flask server. My MQTT code runs locally (visualstudio) but fails under pythonanywhere (code below copied from my similar question on [pythonanywhere forum](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/32253/)).

I configured MQTT credentials and set `tls` to `false` and 5 seconds keepalive then I instantiate `mqtt=Mqtt(app)`. In `@mqtt.onConnect()` function I printed values when `rc` is zero but it doesn't print in any log file (even I used `sys.stderr`) meaning that means it doesn't go in this function, therefore publish and `onMessage()` doesn't work too.

However if I open python in the bash console and import MQTT instance from app file it connects to my broker and when I call the function that publish from the console it publish the message to my broker.

I tried to `mqtt=Mqtt()` then in main scope `mqtt.init_app(app)` and also tried in main `mqtt.run()` didn't work.

```
app1.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'mybroker'
app1.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883
app1.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] = ' '
app1.config['MQTT_PASSWORD'] = ' '
app1.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE'] = 5
app1.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED'] = False

mqtt_client = Mqtt(app1)

import sys as syss

@mqtt_client.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client,userdata,flags,rc):
   if rc == 0:
      print('Connected successfully', file = syss.stderr)
      mqtt_client.subscribe('esp/copra')
   else:
      print('Bad connection. Code:', rc , file=syss.stderr)

testmqtt="a"

@mqtt_client.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client,userdata,message):
   payload = message.payload.decode()
   print("payload is " + payload)

@app1.route("/testmqtt")
def testmqtt():
   print("test mqtt here")
   mqtt_client.publish('esp/copra',"pythonanywhere")
   return{"mqtt": "mqtt"}

if name == "main":
   #app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
   mqtt_client.init_app(app1)
   app1.run()
```

Comment: Enabling [logging](https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#logging) is probably a good starting point. I've tried to reformat/add detail to your question but it would be great if you can provide more info about the broker (are you using a test broker like `broker.emqx.io`?).

Comment: Thanks alot, I'm using my mosquito broker and it is working fine I tested it with MQTT Explorer, and now I am trying to enable logging.

Comment: My guess is that the Mqtt class is spinning off a thread to listen to messages; threading isn't supported inside website code on PythonAnywhere.  This is because it uses multiple processes to handle multiple simultaneous requests, so the code you're using there would spin up an mqtt client for each one.  Is there a particular reason why you're trying to run the client inside the Flask code itself?  Normally you'd have the queue listener in a separate program, perhaps using an always-on task, and it would store data from messages somewhere where the Flask code can access it (eg. MySQL)

Comment: Hi Giles, well if I use my mqtt instance in always-on task how can I use it to publish to the broker when some route is accessed? can you describe the methodology you suggest more

Comment: Just jumping into your convo with Giles -- have a look at this help page on PythonAnywhere: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AsyncInWebApps/